# Refspec does not match on `git push`

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a new cask to Homebrew Cask on GitHub. After entering my username the remote command fails as follows:

```
$ git push "$github_user" fsmonitor
error: src refspec fsmonitor does not match any.
```

I know I've seen this issue before but can't remember how it was resolved. My best guess is that this is a configuration issue with credentials - adding 2 factor auth, while secure, seems to be the root of this.

Perhaps `set-head` or `set-url` needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

This is (or should be) a simple case of the name `fsmonitor` not being a valid branch or tag name in your repository.  Does it show up in `git branch` or `git tag` output?

Comment: It does...sort of. For reasons that are still mysterious to me, Cask recommends PR's originate and push not from the location of your cloned repo - in my case `~/Documents/Homebrew Cask` - but from within `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/Casks` and then making a branch to contain your changes. I've already commited accoring to their instructions, so it's really just pushing a new branch that is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr Branch names matter.

Cask is still weird, tho.